# Term for one "story"/"node"/"item of news"

Tags: nouns

I am not a native speaker of English. If there are many news, we say "there are some news", but what if there is only one "item of news"?

Comment: In English we construe  "news" or "the news" as singular, even if we have in mind multiple separate items of news. Hence, we say "There is some news," "The news is bad today," and "The  news about the invasion is on the front page." When we refer to a single item of news, we may call it a "story," a "report," or a "piece of news," among many other possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

We never say that there are *many* or *some* news. *News*, though it looks like a plural; it means *new information* and like *information* it is a singular, uncountable noun. It has no plural. We say *There **is** **much** news* or *There **is some** news (about something)*.

A single 'piece' of news on a single topic is usually a news *item* or a news *story*, sometimes a *piece*—but with *piece* we are usually speaking of the written or spoken account by a particular journalist.

Answer (score 1):

I usually describe it as a *news item* or *item of news.*